# Wiki engine with look and feel of Mediawiki with access control and rating of article

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, wiki-engine

I am looking for a wiki engine, which has look and feel of Mediawiki but has page level access control. Looked around for various wiki engines but none of them seem to retain the exact look and feel of Mediawiki, although most versions support access control.

Please guide me if you know one. Following are my requirements

1. Mediawiki look and feel
2. Access control
3. Ability for the users to rate the article.
4. Ability to create user profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to add some extensions to mediawiki.

Check out these 2 (I'd give more but this site won't let me post more than 2 links):

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Rating

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SocialProfile

There are also a few that allow you to limit access to mediawiki pages (including one called: Access Control)

Comment: Thank you very much. This sloves the problem. ill explore more about extension